# Java application using netbeans. To perform a click from a text field

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using net-beans to create a java application.
There are 2 text fields and an ok button. 
After input to the second to field, I want an 'enter' press to click the ok button.

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some code you have/ have tried and doesn't work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows lack of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java KeyListeners. You just make your class implement a KeyListener then add an action for the enter key in the keyPressed action.

You can learn how to do this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html